# Android listview in a viewpager not showing results

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am new to android. I am using a viewpager with 4 pages and there is a list view in the first page. When I run my app, the list does not display any items but when I switch three pages and come back to the first one, the listview shows up. I tried changing the offscrren limit for pager but its not working. Please help me on this as I am stuck from many days and not finding an answer to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code?